# Variable value is null in html but has value in constructor

Tags: angular, angular-material

Trying to create a mat-dialog that is created by a menu button in a navbar, then opens a mat-dialog which will perform additional work. I'm able to create the dialog in the navbar component.ts, pass the variable (title) I want to the constructor in dialogs.component.ts, but the variable is null in the component.html. I've tried various ways of referencing the variable, but none work. I log the value in the console, so I know the value is there in the constructor, but how do a access it in the html?

Navbar.component.ts:

```
...
  realTimeTracking() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;
    dialogConfig.width = '60%';
    dialogConfig.data = {
      title: "Real-time Tracking"
    };

    console.log('real-time tracking, dialogConfig.data:', dialogConfig);

    this.dialog.open(DialogsComponent, dialogConfig );

  };

....
```

dialogs.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialogs',
  templateUrl: './dialogs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialogs.component.scss']
})
  export class DialogsComponent implements OnInit {
     title: string;

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogsComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: {title: string} ) { 
                console.log('constructing dialog, data=', data);
                console.log('data.title:', data.title)
                this.title = data.title;
                console.log('this.title:', this.title);
              }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

dialogs.component.html:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>title={{data.title}}</h2>
<h2 mat-dialog-title>title</h2>
<mat-dialog-content >

  <mat-form-field>
    <label>Date/Time Range
      <input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt10" [owlDateTime]="dt10"
             [selectMode]="'range'" style="width: 70%">
      <owl-date-time #dt10></owl-date-time>
    </label>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions align="center">
  <button class="mat-raised-button"(click)="close()">Close</button>
  <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary"(click)="save()">Save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

screen shot of dialog:
[image]
screen shot of console log:
[image]

There must be a simple and obvious thing I'm doing wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the rest of `dialogs.component.ts` please? There maybe something you think is unrelated, but in fact is causing your issue.

Comment: Just updated the post with full source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GaryB pointed out you should do it like:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: {title:string}
```

In your controller, when you say:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: string
```

You're saying that `data` is a string type variable, so when you try to set

```
this.title = data.title
```

it'll fail because `data` doesn't have a property named `title`.

**UPDATE**

You should change your

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>title={{data.title}}</h2>
```

to

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>title={{title}}</h2>
```

since data is a block-scoped variable.

**[A working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajbnta)**

Comment: but when I open the dialog in the navbar button click, I create the title record in dialogConfig. Doesn't that work? 

    dialogConfig.data = {
          title: "Real-time Tracking"
        };

Comment: changed back to {{title}} in html file, but still no value. Is there a way to debug inside the html to see what the DOM has?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be data.title

first line:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>title={{data.title}}</h2>
```

Also in the .ts file the data should be an object like this:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: {title:string}
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt see this:
 this.title = data.title;
then you can use title in the html